# Arrays and pointers

Tags: arrays

so I know the name of the array is a pointer to the first element of the array. But I've noticed something weird  Here's the code.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

How is it possible that the pointer is pointing to itself and when I dereference it, I get the first element of the array? Are arrays implemented using struct? What am I missing here.

Comment: The text of the first message is inaccurate. `What am I missing here` This question is a question about semantics of constructs in one particular programming language you fail to name. Please revisit what's [on-topic here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a Good Question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In low-level programming languages like C, arrays are implemented as a range of memory cells. Moreover, an array variable is just a pointer to the first memory cell. Now let's break the different values that you're printing:

- `a` is the address of the first memory cell.
- `&a` is the same as `a`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) on stackoverflow.
- `*a` is the value found at the address `a`, which is just the first element in the array.
- `a[0]` (which you're not printing) is also the first element in the array.
- `&a[0]` is the address of the first element in the array, which is the same as `a`.

In low-level programming languages like C, structs (also known as records) are also implemented as a range of memory cells. In a sense, an array of length $n$ is just a struct containing $n$ elements, ignoring the issue of [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment); but whereas arrays support access using an index, structs typically do not.